# Can we pass some extra metadata to body of the email specific to the sender end

Tags: gmail-api

I want to show some extra data to the body of mail. Which is in sent-box of sender. Like some extra information from which sender can know why I sent this email to receiver.

If it's possible. Please share the way How to do this.

Thank You!